# Where can I get a list of all the properties available in the project file?

Tags: msbuild, properties, tfsbuild

I'm looking for a resource to list all the built-in properties defined in an MSBuild project file. Specifically I'm using a Team Build project file, but from what I understand they are one in the same (correct me if I'm wrong).

I already know about the reserved properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164309.aspx

But I've noticed other handy variables being referenced in examples, like $(SolutionRoot) and $(OutDir).

Is there a comprehensive list of all the properties I have access to? Where are these other properties defined? I found a forum post where the same question was asked, and it pointed to the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.targets file, but I looked in there and could not find definitions for $(SolutionRoot) and $(OutDir) listed.

Thanks for any help you can give, Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see this: http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/30_useful_team.html

Answer (score 2):

This is another great reference:

http://blogs.msdn.com/aaronhallberg/archive/2008/02/12/team-build-2008-property-reference.aspx

Vaccano